# Change the SRID of a geometry

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

I would like to develop a python code that set the SRID(A Spatial Reference System Identifier (SRID) is a unique value used to unambiguously identify projected, unprojected, and local spatial coordinate system definitions. These coordinate systems form the heart of all GIS applications) of a geometry to a particular integer value, however i don't have a clue from where to start.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question right. I assume you're using PostgreSQL/PostGIS, so you're looking for a way to set the `CRS` of existing geometries? Or you want to extract it from them?

Comment: Not, really. I want to develop a function using python that does the same thing as the function st_setsrid() of posgis in postgresql

Comment: Have you check this? http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: @SachiTekina, can you please explain what gdal do ?

Answer (score 1):

To implement such a function that mimics ST_SetSRID outside of PostGIS, you need to decide on the format you're willing to operate in.

If you're looking at geometry in EWKT (Extended Well-Known Text), then SRID is stored in the beginning:

```
SRID=4326;POINT(10.23 10.41)
```

There it can be replaced using text manipulation functions.

If you are looking at geom in EWKB (Extended Well-Known Binary), then SRID is stored as an integer after a header, if a header has a flag that it stores a SRID raised.

Here is how postgis stores a flag:
https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/postgis/postgis/-/blob/liblwgeom/lwout_wkb.c#L145

Here is how it writes the SRID value:
https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/postgis/postgis/-/blob/liblwgeom/lwout_wkb.c#L583

If you are implementing it in Python, you may want to use something like WKBheader library to not manipulate the fields youself:
https://github.com/MazeMap/wkbheader